# Count uppercase on each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to create a new column with values equal to the sum/count of uppercases in another column. (fastest way cuz I have a semi-wood pc)
Ex:

```
         Col1                     Upper

1      AfK is Bad                   3
2      Afk is bad                   1
3      Python better than R         2
```

EDIT:
I have tries this:

```
 for i in df.index:
     df['Upper'].iloc[[i]] = sum(1 for c in (df['Upper'].iloc[[i]]) if c.isupper())
```

where 'Upper' is Col1

Many thanks !

Comment: what did you try so far

Comment: for i in df.index:
     df['Upper'].iloc[[i]] = sum(1 for c in (df['Upper'].iloc[[i]]) if c.isupper())
but it takes ages so I don't know the results (btw here I am changing same col)

Comment: You could have edited the post rather than posting in comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`pd.Series.str.count`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with the regex `[A-Z]`

```
df.assign(Upper=df.Col1.str.count('[A-Z]'))

                   Col1  Upper
1            AfK is Bad      3
2            Afk is bad      1
3  Python better than R      2
```

Comment: @hdatas glad I could help.

Comment: Here it is again:) +1

Comment: Well half anyway